# Ubuntu does not start

Tags: boot

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. On powering on grub loader asks me to boot normally or in recovery mode.

On booting normally it checks the hard disk for errors and stops at 80% and on ignoring it I can get to the login screen but on entering my login information it shows an error saying `panic occurred switching back to text console!`.

I cant get any further... Cant get further in recovery mode also! somebody please help O don't have the backup of my data and its pretty important!

---

Yes I only asked the question bruno! I tried both of them on live usb! 11.10 and 12.04..but they don't start! It reaches till the ubuntu loading screen and then it shuts down just like that!

Comment: I am unclear what your question is. To recover important data load a live CD/USB and copy the data to somewhere else. To fix what is wrong a lot more information is needed. Such as what you were doing to the system before this problem started. A re-install might be the simple way to fix this. When Grub gives you a recovery mode option it is a message that something is very wrong either with the hardware or the operating system. If a live CD/USB loads we might be able to discount the hardware.

Comment: @BrunoPereira Right below the comments...

Comment: No, what says there is that 12.04 also does not start, this question is about Ubuntu 11.10: `I am using Ubuntu 11.10. On powering on grub loader asks me to boot normally or in recovery mode.`.

Comment: Ignore one flag (mine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if it starts checking the disk is because there are some problems.

You should use a live system and check the disks from there with

```
sudo fsck -fv /dev/sdXY
```

where XY are the letter and the number of the partitions you would check.

Check all the partitions, and if you've got some FAT/NTFS partitions boot with a Microsoft system and make sure you check them from there.